# Why does scipy provide a nonzero result for the integral where the result should be zero?

Tags: python, scipy, integral

Given the following function:

```
d = y-a*sin(b*x-c)
```

I integrate this function over specific bounds for a, b and c using `nquad` from `scipy`:

```
def Iper(x,y,alb,aub,blb,bub,clb,cub):
    return nquad(lambda a,b,c: y-a*np.sin(b*x-c), [[alb,aub],[blb,bub], [clb,cub]], full_output=True)
```

using the boundaries below:

```
print(Iper(5.0,3.0,
           1.5,2.0,
           4.3,4.5,
           7.5,8.0))
```

I get the following result:

```
(0.09107123193614816, 1.2123921401960992e-14, {'neval': 9261})
```

However the result should be (best to my knowledge) zero. Plotting the resulting d values for the given bounds yields an area which is by no means intersected by the function of d. Below you see the function of d with the axis b, c and d. The green and violet curve are for the a values `a = 1.5` and `a = 2.0`. The eight points represent the 'box'/area encompassed by the bounds of a, b, c and d... none of the two drawn functions intersect with this box area. How does it come that we have here an integral which does not equal zero?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misinterpreting what a 3 dimensional multivariate integral measures. It's not the 3d volume of the intersection of the domain and the curves (this is what a 2d multivariate integral measures), but the 4 dimensional hypervolume.

---

Looking at this integral step by step, first integrating with respect to `a`:

[image: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+y-a*sin(b*x-c)+with+respect+to+a+between+1.5+and+2]

Then `b`:

[image: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+0.5+y+%2B+0.875+sin(c+-+b+x)+with+respect+to+b+between+4.3+and+4.5]

Then `c`:

[image: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+0.1+y+%2B+(0.875+(cos(c+-+4.5+x)+-+cos(c+-+4.3+x)))%2Fx+with+respect+to+c+between+7.5+and+8]

We see the integral is non-zero for the given values of x and y.

---

**Note:** when I evaluated this I got:

```
(0.06749972471060735, 1.031215181499445e-14, {'neval': 9261})
```

instead of your answer.

Comment: Ah, as we have a four dimensional space (a,b,c,d), with the a-dimension being represented through the two plots, I miss in this representation the fact that with the a-dimension a hypervolume is present which I can not grasp in this representation. In this context the question arises: how can I visualize the hypervolume in lower dimensional projections to 'visually' see if the 4d hypervolume is intersected by a curve?

Comment: @Daniyal with great difficulty, I think is the only answer here. I unfortunately don't know of any tricks to gain intuition for visualising 4 dimensional spaces like this. You could do the integration step by step to see why (mathematically) it results in non zero terms.

Comment: thank you for your detailed response. Regarding the result: you are right, I got one line down to the next test case. Your computed value is correct.